# Neo4J using apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce with special characters like -, / or ( )

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using Neo4J version 4.4.5 Community with a docker-compose file. I included the apoc plugin, so I am able to use "apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce()". I am using OSM as provider.

The problem now is that I have predefined address that can contain special characters like -, / or ( )

When I am using

```
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce("Eisenstadt (Stadt)")
```

I get no results but when I am entering the same in the Open Street Map website, I get a result which you can see in the link below.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Eisenstadt%20(Stadt)%20#map=13/47.8455/16.5249

So I am wondering why I don´t get a result back from apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce but the I get a result at the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Have you tried any location which does not include these special characters?

Comment: I got no error, I just get 0 results

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce("Eisenstadt (Stadt)")
YIELD location//,data
RETURN location.latitude, location.longitude,location.description
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply update the apoc version.
I just tried with `4.4.0.1` and `4.4.0.5` versions.
With the first it doesn't work, with the second it does,
maybe because of some encoding fixes done after the 1st version.